# $f(z)$ is constant on a path $\rightarrow f'(z) = 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z): D\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ is in analytic in $D$ and constant on a diffrentiable path $\Gamma$.
Is necessarily $f'(z) =0$ for every $z \in Γ$? proove or give an example against.
Tried to solve it without success.
I will be happy for help.
thanks :)

Comment: If $f'(z)\ne0$ then $f$ would be invertible in some neighborhood of $z$ and therefore cannot be constant on some path containing $z$. (This assumes that $D$ is some open subset of $\mathbb{C}$)

Comment: I didn't understant what invertible means in that context. if you can explain what you mean it would be great

Comment: What are the assumptions on $D?$ What exactly is a differentiable path? Is $\Gamma$ a map or a set?

Answer (score 0):

If there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f=c$ on $\Gamma$ then the zeros of $f-c$ are not isolated because for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$, if $|u-v|<\delta$ then $|\Gamma(u)-\Gamma(v)|<\varepsilon$. Therefore if $u\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists $v\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\Gamma(v)\in D(\Gamma(u),\varepsilon)$ and there is no isolated points in $\Gamma$. According to the isolated zeros principle, $f$ is constant on the connected part of $D$ containing $\Gamma$, so in particular $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in\Gamma$.

**EDIT :** Here is another solution : since $f$ and $\Gamma$ are differentiable, then $f\circ\Gamma$ is also differentiable. $f\circ\Gamma$ being constant, we have $\Gamma'(t)f'(\Gamma(t))=0$ for all $t$. I suppose that $\Gamma$ is never constant (that means there is no $a<b$ such that $\Gamma_{|(a,b)}$ is constant), otherwise of course if $\Gamma$ is a constant path it does not work, and if $\Gamma_{|(a,b)}$ is constant then you can get rid of $\Gamma(t)$ for $t\in (a,b)$ by juxtaposing $\Gamma(a)$ with $\Gamma(b)$. Therefore if $\Gamma'(t)\neq 0$ then $f'(\Gamma(t))=0$ and if $\Gamma(t)=0$, there exists a sequence $(t_n)$ converging toward $t$ and such that $\Gamma'(t_n)\neq 0$ for all $n$ (this is because $\Gamma$ is never constant). Hence $f'(\Gamma(t_n))=0$ for all $n$ and taking as limit as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ gives $f'(\Gamma(t))=0$.

Comment: thanks!
but we didn't learn this yet so I can't use that theorm. I think we are just required to use the derivative by definition here

Comment: I edited my answer, adding another proof withtout using the isolated zeros principle.

Comment: thanks!
I have another idea but I don't know if it is ok..
just use the derivative by definition..I'll upload it and I'll be happy for your opinion about the corretness of that way